# Python Requests Throwing SSL Error

Tags: python, ssl, python-requests

I am running a Python script in 2 environment using Requests Package.

The Script is working fine in one Environment where,

```
RedHat version is : Red Hat Enterprise Linux Server release 6.5 (Santiago)
OpenSSL version is : OpenSSL 1.0.1e-fips 11 Feb 2013
Python Version is : Python 2.6.6 (r266:84292, Sep  4 2013, 07:46:00)
Requests Package is : requests-2.7.0-py2.6
```

But The Same Script is throwing the SSL Error in another Environment where,

```
RedHat version is : Red Hat Enterprise Linux Server release 6.5 (Santiago)
OpenSSL version is : OpenSSL 1.0.1e-fips 11 Feb 2013
Python Version is : Python 2.6.6 (r266:84292, Sep  4 2013, 07:46:00)
Requests Package is : requests-2.7.0-py2.6
```

Error is:

```
raise SSLError(e, request=request)
requests.exceptions.SSLError: [Errno 1] _ssl.c:492: error:100AE081:elliptic curve routines:EC_GROUP_new_by_curve_name:unknown group
```

I am calling the URL as below

```
requests.request('GET', url, verify=False, headers = headers)
```

Can anyone please help me in resolving the above error

Answer (score 4):

you can try updating your openSSL package. The issue is with compatibility of the package with linux . You might get further help by referring to the link:- https://bugzilla.redhat.com/show_bug.cgi?id=1023331

Comment: The OpenSSL versions are exactly same in the two different servers as detailed in the question, but it works in one and doesn't work in the other. Do you think it is still the OpenSSL verion issue

Answer (score 0):

You need to update your system to get a newer version of the OpenSSL package.
Even if `openssl version` reports the same version `1.0.1e-fips` the OpenSSL libraries on both systems differ probably because RedHat added patches. It is common to not upgrade to a newer OpenSSL version if patches are needed but instead apply the patch to the current version to keep compatibility for existing applications.

If you check the version of the rpm package with `rpm -qi` you will notice that the package version differs on both machines so an upgrade should fix the issue for you.

Comment: Hi Steffen,
I have checked the rpm -qi openssl in both the environment, But both are exactly same.

Comment: @Navya: then I would recommend to make a packet capture (with tcpdump or wireshark) and compare, especially the ClientHello. If you need help put the packet capture on cloudshark.org.